# If $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \cong S_2$, why isn't $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z) \cong \mathrm{Aut}(S_2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

We know $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z) \cong (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$. So  $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z) \cong \{0\}$.

In Dummit & Foote, Section $4.4$, Proposition $17$ says if $n \ne 6$, then $\mathrm{Aut}(S_n) \cong S_n$. So we have $\mathrm{Aut}(S_2) \cong S_2$.

We know $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \cong S_2$.

How come we don't have $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z) \cong \mathrm{Aut}(S_2)$?

Comment: Your second line is incorrect - $Aut(S_n)\cong S_n$ iff $n\neq 2,6$.

Comment: So, there's an error in Dummit & Foote.

Comment: Books are written by fallible mortals, not by the gods, who by their nature are infallible. I suppose there never was a book written by human hand that is without the stain of error.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to say gods are infallible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\operatorname{Aut}(S_n) \cong S_n$ for $n \ne 2$ or $6$. Actually the rule is that every automorphism of $S_n$ is inner for $n \ne 6$ but because $S_2$ is Abelian, every inner automorphism is trivial.

Comment: Said another way, $S_2$ is the only symmetric group with nontrivial center, and so its inner automorphism group is a nontrivial quotient of it.